# Variável em decimal removendo as casas decimais

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, postgresql, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho uma variável em `decimal` que recebe um valor de um *textbox*, porém quando essa variável recebe o valor com casas decimais ele remove a casa decimal e guarda o valor sem a mesma.

O que acontece:

- Valor do TextBox: 2.5;
- Valor da variável: 0;

  ```
  variavel = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox);
  variavel = 25;
  ```

Não estou conseguindo entender o porque está acontecendo isto. Dá erro de inserção no banco de dados:

> NpgsqlException was unhandled by user code ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "3"

Comment: Deixa eu entender melhor, o que aparece se você imprimir o valor do `TextBox` antes de gravar?

Comment: Aparece 2,5 - mas se eu inserir 2,5 no POSTGRE na hora da inserção ele da erro. Porque nenhum tipo de dado do postgre aceita virgula, porém quando eu estou manipulando o textbox e eu coloco .Replace(",",".") e mando o valor do txt pro numeric e o numeric recebe o valor ele já recebe sem o .

Comment: @LucasVasconcelos você precisa passar mais detalhes então. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Se o erro está ocorrendo porque um dado foi digitado de forma incorreta, o que falta é uma validação. Você deve evitar usar qualquer dado sem antes ter certeza que ele é adequado para uso. Você nunca pode confiar em entrada de dados, ainda mais pela *web*.

Você pode fazer a conversão desta forma:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        decimal valor;
        if (decimal.TryParse("123.45", out valor)) WriteLine(valor);
        if (decimal.TryParse("123,45", NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), out valor)) {
            WriteLine(valor);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EouqjY). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/luAGUV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Decimal/PointComma.cs).

Coloquei duas formas para você ver como pode ser feito. Você pode ler a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Decimal__) para aprender outras formas de usar a conversão de forma apropriada.

Comment: Gostaria de saber qual é o erro aqui para ter um -1?

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive esse mesmo problema esses dias,
no meu caso usei javascript com expressão regular  para corrigir o erro da seguinte forma.

remover todos os ponto do texto.

```
str = str.replace(/\./g, "");
```

altera a , por ponto

```
str = str.replace(",", ".");
```

Qual motivo para isso? os campo do tipo (`Decimal , numeric`) do `SQL SERVER` não aceitam `,` para especificar as casas decimais.

Os métodos abaixo pode ajudar com algumas coisas.

// ----- Decimal Extensions -----

```
public static Boolean IsValidDecimal(this String numStr)
{
    Decimal Dummy;
    return Decimal.TryParse(numStr.Replace(".", String.Empty),
        NumberStyles.Float, new CultureInfo(1046, true), out Dummy);
}

public static Decimal StringToDecimal(this String numStr)
{
    return Decimal.Parse(numStr.Replace(".", String.Empty), 
        NumberStyles.Float, new CultureInfo(1046, true));
}

public static Decimal? StringToNullableDecimal(this String numStr)
{
    Decimal? DecVal = null;
    if (!numStr.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        DecVal = numStr.StringToDecimal();
    return DecVal;
}

// Converte um Decimal para um String com 2 casos decimais
public static String DecimalToString(this Decimal dec, Int32 scale = 2)
{
    return dec.ToString("#,##0.00000000".Substring(0, 6 + scale),
                new CultureInfo(1046, true));
}

public static String DecimalToString(this Decimal? dec, Int32 scale = 2)
{
    return dec.HasValue ? dec.Value.DecimalToString(scale): String.Empty;
}

public static String DecimalToSqlString(this Decimal dec, Int32 scale = 2)
{
    return dec.ToString("0.000000".Substring(0, 2 + scale),
                new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
}

public static String DecimalToSqlString(this Decimal? dec, Int32 scale = 2)
{
    return dec.HasValue ? dec.Value.DecimalToSqlString(scale) : "null";
}

 public static Boolean IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this String str)
{
    return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str);
}
```