# Convertendendo String para Decimal?

Tags: c#

Estou tentando converter um valor monetário para decimal, o valor `1.000,00`. Quando faço a conversão e exibido apenas o número inteiro `100000` o ponto decimal deixa de existir.

Como resolver isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

```
string s = "1.000,00";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s.Replace(".","").Replace(",", "."));
Console.WriteLine(d);
//console output = 100000
```

Comment: Solução alternativa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48425/101 Uma mais personalizada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44962/101

Comment: @bigown no caso do link q vc flw estão usando para exibição eu quero formatar pra gravar no banco de dados. No caso de gravar no banco de dados deve ser com ponto e não virgula, correto ?

Comment: Não importa onde será usado. Depois que é convertido para decimal, é um número, não existe isso de ponto.Número não é texto.

Comment: vou testar, qquer coisa aviso aqui.

Comment: Você está convertendo "1.000,00" para "1000.00" e então para decimal, e no último passo obtem 100000 como resultado? Tem certeza que seu ambiente reconhece "." como o separador de decimais, ou está usando formato brasileiro e espera "," aí?